# (first author et al. 1999; first author et al. 2000)

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, apa-style

I have downloaded MiKTeX and it works very well.  However I am wondering if you could you help me about the citation style.  I want to cite more than one reference as (First Author et al. 1999; First Author et al. 2000).

This is the code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{92,
  Author = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C.},
  Journal = {Journal of modeling},
  Pages = {1--2},
  Title = {----},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1999}
}

@article{Grady,
  Author = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C.},
  Journal = {Journal of food},
  Pages = {1--4},
  Title = {food},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage[options]{natbib}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\citep{92,Grady}
I want the output as (First Author et al. 1999; First Author et al. 2000) 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Start by looking for `natbib` or `biblatex`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to hand the citation commands over to `natbib`, without interference for `apacite`.   By default repeated author lists are suppressed, using `\citealt` you can make them explicit at the price of having to use this for each citation separately:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[nocitation]{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{92,Grady}

(\citealt{92}; \citealt{Grady})

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{ref} 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: how to cite two references with the same author and the same year but different journal. This is because i cannot see the difference when i cite these papers in the text. Thus how to make it clear

Comment: If there are two such references, then the coding I give above will  add a letter to the end of the year to distinguish them, e.g. 2000a and 2000b.